# How to add an integer to this sentence?

Tags: python, integer, conditional-statements, multiplication, money-format

I am trying to make python run a statement that looks like this.

```
"How much did you make this year: " #Enter amount here in cash

"Expect to pay (4% of your amount in cash) in taxes this year."
```

Comment: Use the input function https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```py
pay = int(input("How much did you make this year:"))
print(f"Expect to pay {pay * 0.04} in taxes this year.")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 0.04?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, thanks for pointing in out (fixed the error).

Comment: @longanddog Do not forget to accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it if it helped.

Answer (score -1):

val = input("How much did you make this year:")

print("Expect to pay "+str(0.04*float(val))+ " in taxes this year.")

Comment: Concatenating strings using `+` is frowned upon in Python.